# Enable/disable popups lively in Plotly plot

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible to somehow add the option to enable/disable the popups in plotly but lively? I mean, I don't want to remove them from the plot, but I would like to be able to enable/disable them with some kind of check box like I have drawn below:

[image]

Is this possible?

If an example is needed, anyone from [here](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#scatter-plots-with-plotly-express) can be used, e.g.:

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", symbol="species")
fig.show()
```

If there is a global setting that controls this for all the plots, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using `hovermode=False` for disabling and `hovermode="closest"` for enabling.

**Full code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", symbol="species")


fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["hovermode", "closest"],
                    label="Enabled",
                    method="relayout"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["hovermode", False],
                    label="Disabled",
                    method="relayout"
                )
            ]),
            direction="down",
            showactive=True,
            x=0.0,
            y=1.1,
            xanchor="left",
            yanchor="top"
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]